# How to compare with the data that has been encrypted by Real AES

Tags: 8

I stored some serial numbers after encrypting them by Real AES.

```
$data1 = 'S45Qaz6635';
$profile = EnryptionProfile::load('my_encryption_profile');
$result = Drupal::service('encryption')->encrypt($data1, $profile);

$query = INSERT INTO ... VALUES ($result)
```

Then, I have a form for user to type serial number. If the number does not exist in database, I should return some error messages.

First I came up with an idea is to encrypt that number which user typed, and compare with all numbers in database.

```
$data2 = 'S45Qaz6635';
$profile = EnryptionProfile::load('my_encryption_profile');
$result = Drupal::service('encryption')->encrypt($data2, $profile);

$query = SELECT * FROM ... WHERE column = {$result}
```

But I found the result of $query is always null. Because the result of encrypting $data2 is not as same as the result of encrypting $data1.

Second idea is to select all numbers in database, decrypting them, then use in_array() function to figure out the result. But I think it's too inefficient.

Here are some pictures of the setting!

I generated 256-bit key on the website.
[image]

Setting of Key:
[image]

Setting of Encryption Profile:
[image]

I'm using drupal core version 8.

What can I do to work around this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Your first idea of encrypting $data2 and then using that in your MYSQL lookup should work. Either the returned value in $result isnt a string so might be worth checking that. Or your encryption method is using something variable to encrypt like the current time or something

Comment: @Leigh Thanks for the reply. Both of $result are string, and they are totally different. I also checked the setting of Key and Encryption Profile but I couldn't find out if the encryption method is using something like current time to encrypt.

Comment: It sounds like the method you are using to encrypt the value is not the same as your system is. I unfortunately don't have the solution to this, but Leigh's advice was sound, and I'd focus on trying to figure out how the system is doing it so you can match that.